# The password reset link 'has expired. Please submit your request again;

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When resetting a password for a user, it has happened on several occasions that the link that was generated by Snowflake was expired, even seconds after generating the link. Can it be the case that password links do not work for MFA enabled users ? Or has anyone other experiences or possible causes for this behaviour ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it consistently reproducible (maybe 1 out of 5 times that you try it)?  How are you sending the link to the user (or are using it yourself and it still expires immediately)?

Comment: It looks like tools like MS Teams validate a link, therefore using it, which means that after this validation, the link is not valid anymore

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. If any program is scanning the link, it will invalidate it.  Perhaps sending it within an attachment may help? And/Or adding an element to the end of the URL that the user can remove?